# What configuration bits should be used to debug PIC16F1947?

Tags: c, configuration, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm stuck with configuration bits with PIC16F1947. I'm new to PIC programming so please answer in details.

I've the following setup:

- MPLAB 8.46
- MPLAB ICD 3
- HI-TECH C Compiler 9.81

A PIC16F1947 PIM (Plug in module) is plugged on PICDEM LCD 2 Demo Board. The board is powered by 3 V battery and J15 jumper was connected according to the manual (1-3 connected, 2-4 connected on J15). The project is compiled as **debug build**.

Following are the configuration bits used:

```
// Configuration word 1
__CONFIG(   FOSC_INTOSC &  // INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin
            WDTE_OFF &      // WDT disabled
            PWRTE_OFF &     // PWRT disabled
            MCLRE_OFF &     // MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input
            CP_OFF &        // Program memory code protection is disabled
            CPD_OFF &       // Data memory code protection is disabled
            BOREN_OFF &     // Brown-out Reset disabled
            CLKOUTEN_OFF &  // CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin
            IESO_OFF &      // Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled
            FCMEN_OFF       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled
);

// Configuration word 2
__CONFIG(   WRT_OFF &      // Write protection off
            VCAPEN_OFF &    // VCAP pin functionality is disabled
            PLLEN_OFF &     // 4x PLL disabled
            STVREN_OFF &    // Stack Overflow or Underflow will not cause a Reset
            BORV_19 &       // Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 1.9 V
            LVP_OFF         // High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming
);
```

I **can program (burn firmware)** the micro via MPLAB. But when I try to `Debugger > Run` it, the output windows shows following error:

> ICD3Err0040: The target device is not
>   ready for debugging. Please check your
>   configuration bit settings and program
>   the device before proceeding.

I've checked the documentation about ICD3Err0040 but it seems to me that everything is alright.

What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: perhaps more luck here? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded MPLAB IDE from `8.46` to `8.63` and debugging started to work!!!

May be they had issue with previous version.

Answer (score 0):

IN CONFIG WORD 1 WRITE:- ICS_PGx2  SHOULD WORK

Answer (score 0):

[Debugger>Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEril.png)

Invokes the msg box shown above.
Click [ok] and the IDE will modify the configuration bits appropriately to permit debugging.

For those who cannot see the pic shown above.
Single -Supply ICSP Enable bit must disabled
Watchdog Timer Enable bit must be disabled